# duplicates in 2 dimensional array

Tags: ruby

I i'm doing a simple lottery game. at the moment its taking serial number and lottery number from a txt file, and putting them in a 2 dimensional array.

now i want to make a check grade if there are any duplicates of the serial number and lottery number

```
example:
5153,177 = 1
54338,115 = 1
74522,171 = 3
```

i've tried making a check number method, it do not give any errors, but when i do

```
puts sold.checkgrade
```

it do not work

How can i make it do like in my example?

```
class Lottery

    attr_accessor :lotnumber
    attr_accessor :serialnumber


    def initialize(lotnumber, serialnumber)
       @lotnumber = lotnumber
       @serialnumber = serialnumber
    end

    def checknumber
       ObjectSpace.each_object(Lottery).to_a.select do |other|
       @lotnumber == other.lotnumber && @serialnumber == other.serialnumber
       end.size
    end

end
```

my txt

```
29371,43
13797,6
8114,55
70657,106
32741,74
7272,103
37416,14
5153,177
54338,115
74522,171
74522,171
74522,171
```

Comment: Hey user! Please indent your code correctly. Also, Ruby uses `_`'s to separate words in variable and function names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method is a good place to start:

```
data = %w[
  29371,43
  13797,6
  8114,55
  70657,106
  32741,74
  7272,103
  37416,14
  5153,177
  54338,115
  74522,171
  74522,171
  74522,171
]

data.group_by{ |s| s }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] } 
# => [["29371,43", 1],
#     ["13797,6", 1],
#     ["8114,55", 1],
#     ["70657,106", 1],
#     ["32741,74", 1],
#     ["7272,103", 1],
#     ["37416,14", 1],
#     ["5153,177", 1],
#     ["54338,115", 1],
#     ["74522,171", 3]]
```

The inner magic is, `group_by` creates a hash of arrays:

```
data.group_by{ |s| s }
# => {"29371,43"=>["29371,43"],
#     "13797,6"=>["13797,6"],
#     "8114,55"=>["8114,55"],
#     "70657,106"=>["70657,106"],
#     "32741,74"=>["32741,74"],
#     "7272,103"=>["7272,103"],
#     "37416,14"=>["37416,14"],
#     "5153,177"=>["5153,177"],
#     "54338,115"=>["54338,115"],
#     "74522,171"=>["74522,171", "74522,171", "74522,171"]}
```

If you want a hash instead of an array of arrays:

```
Hash[data.group_by{ |s| s }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }]
# => {"29371,43"=>1,
#     "13797,6"=>1,
#     "8114,55"=>1,
#     "70657,106"=>1,
#     "32741,74"=>1,
#     "7272,103"=>1,
#     "37416,14"=>1,
#     "5153,177"=>1,
#     "54338,115"=>1,
#     "74522,171"=>3}
```

Comment: AWESOME, but how come it writes #<Lottery:0x007fc95187fad8> instead of serialnumber and lotterynumber

Comment: Which writes that? But, in any case, it doesn't display that on my machine, it only shows what I put in the answer using IRB, PRY and Sublime Text with Ruby 2.0.0-p247 to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working example, just with the names changed.

Try running this code and then modifying the names to match your project.

```
class Counter
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_accessor :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a, @b = a, b
  end

  def check_duplicates
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self.class).to_a.select do |other|
      @a == other.a && @b == other.b
    end.size
  end
end


two_match = Counter.new(1, 2) # 2 Matches
duplicate = Counter.new(1, 2)
no_match  = Counter.new(1, 1) # 1 Match

puts two_match.check_duplicates
# => 2

puts no_match.check_duplicates
# => 1
```

Comment: `<main>': undefined method `check_duplicates' for #<Lottery:0x007fa3c987fb58 @lotnumber=1, @serialnumber=2> (NoMethodError)
i get this error now

can you explain the (1, 2) and (1, 1) whats these numbers?

Comment: okay seems to work, but these numbers

(1, 2) and (1, 1)
what do these numbers do?

Comment: Those numbers are just placeholders instead of the longer ones which you had presented.

Comment: now it prints
5153 177 has been sold:1 times
54338 115 has been sold:1 times
74522 171 has been sold:3 times
74522 171 has been sold:3 times
74522 171 has been sold:3 times

which is great. an easy way to only make it write it 1 time if the serial and lotnumber are the same?

Comment: You are look for a way to make the function return `1` if the `serial_number == lot_number`?

Comment: 29371 43 = 1
13797 6 = 1
8114 55 = 1
70657 106 = 1
32741 74 = 1
7272 103 = 1
37416 14 = 1
5153 177 = 1
54338 115 = 1
74522 171 = 3
74522 171 = 3
74522 171 = 3

this is what its printing now which is great.
but as you can see there is no reason to be 3 of the last since its the same serial and lotterynumber. can i remove 2 of them so it is only there once that 3 has been sold

Comment: Are you asking how to remove duplicates?